# SVG as a ReactComponent- Is it possible to get width in render

Tags: reactjs, svg

import { ReactComponent as SVGTest } from '../images/299.svg'

Is there a way to extract the width from the SVGTest during the return.

I want to compare the default width of the SVG vs the width of the window. If less than I want to use the SVG width.

At the moment I set the width to 290px for ALL hundreds of SVGs in the App and the height adjusts accordingly.

However some SVGs are wider and for those I would prefer to use its width over my default 290px.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid hardcoding your SVG, also it's a good practice to treat SVG as a component.

Try resetting your SVG's `width`, `height` with CSS and use [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) for scalling.

This way it will scale its container (`Box` in the next example)

```
const Box = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  background-color: palevioletred;
`;

const SVGContainer = styled.div`
  svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
`;

// Default width,height of SVG are 100px
const App = () => (
  <Box>
    <SVGContainer>
      <SVG />
    </SVGContainer>
  </Box>
);
```

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]